# Class toggle, traversing events, best practices

Tags: javascript, function, events

I've been rummaging through objects in events on the console, to try to link two HTML elements together.

**I'm trying to write a (vanilla Javascript) function that will toggle a class on a different element to that one that is clicked.**

This is the path I found to get to the body of content I want to show on click.

```
function toggleActive() {
    let bodyClassList = event.path[2].children[1].classList;
    bodyClassList.add("active");
};

document.querySelector("#head").addEventListener("click", toggleActive);
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="head" class="headTab">
            <h3>clicked header tab</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="body" class="bodyContent">
            <ul>
                <li>li here</li>
                <li>li here</li>
                <li>li here</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I was wondering if this would be classed as messy code? Or unreliable code, if so why? Is there a better, more widely used approach I haven't come across?

Other examples I have seen aren't using this approach despite it being much less code - I figured there must be a reason for that.

Thanks for any response.

*PS sorry about crappy title really wasn't sure which area was more specific.*

Comment: Despite it being much less code than what? And what’s `event.path`?

Comment: Not sure what `event` is, and the `2` and `1` seem a bit like magic numbers. Regardless, SO generally isn't the place for possibly opinion-based code review

Comment: Less code than what I've seen others do when trying to toggle a class on an element that wasn't the clicked element, without using ids/class names etc so that it is easily reusable. event.path is the paths that come from the even.target on an event.listener. Maybe I'm asking in the wrong place like CertainPerformance mentioned.

Comment: `path` is a non-standard property on events and it doesn’t exist in Firefox. If you could provide a concrete example of “more code” and explain what the event listener is supposed to do logically, that would be helpful.

Comment: This looks like pretty brittle code that would break from making small changes to the markup.

Comment: Here is a JS fiddle if it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/ucm4zq7s/ JLRishe this is what I was looking for, as I thought it looked brittle myself but I couldn't put any reasoning behind it other than what Ry has already stated. Could you elaborate more? I'm starting to feel I have asked this sort of question in the wrong place...?

Comment: @11-: https://jsfiddle.net/ucm4zq7s/1/ is shorter, works in all browsers, and doesn’t need to be updated for as many types of structure changes. `.querySelector(".bodyContent")` instead of `.children[1]` would also make the intent a lot more clear.

Comment: querySelector(".bodyContent") would also make it unique to that code though, I wanted to keep it reusable. But you fiddle, on the other hand, is great, much easier path, and cleaner, thank you.

Comment: @Ry- I was wondering a similar thing about using classList.toggle, is it also not recommended? Such as, https://jsfiddle.net/6af7xLb9/

Comment: @11-: It’s not reusable. It hardcodes `.children[1]`. `classList.toggle` is fine.

Comment: @Ry- As long as the HTML followed the right structure it could be used elsewhere though right? Do you have any suggestions for something I could look into to make it reusable without worrying about that? And, thank you.

Comment: @11-: Classes are a pretty common way to define reusable structure. If `.bodyContent` is specific to the one project, keep in mind that the point of classes is that an element can have more than one. `class="bodyContent expand-this"` and select `.expand-this`.